# Problems with GWT-Pratform PlaceManager + Gin

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-platform

I've trying to do something with GWT-Platform, but, following the examples in this page: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6 simple doesn't work.

I got the following error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Internal error, PlaceRequest passed to updateHistory doesn't match the tail of the place hierarchy.
>       at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.updateHistory(PlaceManagerImpl.java:489)
>       at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract$3$1.execute(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:208)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:228)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushPostEventPumpCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:388)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Flusher.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:138)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

when I try to make a PlaceRequest.

I guess it occurs because PlaceManager is injected, and, someway, it aren't as singleton, but, following the wiki (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6#Binding_everything_together):

> Installing DefaultModule saves you from having to perform all the following bindings: 
>    bind(EventBus.class).to(SimpleEventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);
>       bind(TokenFormatter.class).to(ParameterTokenFormatter.class).in(Singleton.class);
>       bind(RootPresenter.class).asEagerSingleton();
>       bind(PlaceManager.class).to(MyPlaceManager.class).in(Singleton.class);
>       bind(GoogleAnalytics.class).to(GoogleAnalyticsImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);

place manager already has to be a singleton... but, it simply dont work.

Someone has this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time I get this exception, it's because the PlaceRequest I pass to updateHistory doesn't have the same NameToken as the current place, which is not legal.
What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: i'm trying to make it go from #!home to #!adduser, but, i think i've do something wrong, following the example with nested presenters it works..

Comment: Then you shouldn't call updateHistory(), try with revealPlace() instead.

Answer (score 3):

Having just had this problem with gwtp 0.6, I found a solution for my problem.

The problem turned out to be that I bound my implementation of PlaceManager in the ClientModule class:

```
  protected void configure() {
    // Singletons
    install(new DefaultModule(ClientPlaceManager.class));
    ...
```

and then automatically bound my same implementation in the presenter constructor

```
  private ClientPlaceManager placeManager ; //wrong - should be the interface

  @Inject
  public FrameworkLayoutPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view, final MyProxy proxy, 
      final ClientPlaceManager placeManager) //wrong - should be the interface
  {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy);
    this.placeManager = placeManager ;
    ...
```

But I should have bound the interface PlaceManager

```
  private PlaceManager placeManager ; 

  @Inject
  public FrameworkLayoutPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view, final MyProxy proxy, 
      final PlaceManager placeManager) 
  {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy);
    this.placeManager = placeManager ;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using GTWP 0.6 you could use the DefaultModule in this way:

```
public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
         install(new DefaultModule(MyPlaceManager.class));
}
```

The DefaultModule takes care of Binding EventBus, TokenFormatter, RootPresenter, PlaceManager and GoogleAnalytics.